# Stuck on this propositional logic problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I previously asked for help a couple hours ago and decided to tackle on this problem:

(A ∨ B) ∧ (A→C) ∧ (B→C)→C

I'm stuck; this is what I have so far:

1. A ∨ B (*hypothesis*)
2. A→C   (*hypothesis*)
3. B→C  (*hypothesis*)
4. A'∨C (*2, implication*)
5. B'∨C (*3, implication*)

and then I don't know what to do/prove next. Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: Change the title of your question: what you have now is not informative.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$
(A' \lor C) \land (B' \lor C) \equiv (A' \land B') \lor C \equiv (A \lor B)' \lor C
$$

Comment: THANK YOU! I was able to solve after your hint. Thank you so much.